# How to make SaveAs in its original path folder instead of "My document"

Tags: vba, ms-word

So basically I got this working with the code below to save a file with date as name by default.

```
Sub 巨集8()
'
    Dim xDlg As Dialog
    Dim xTitle As String
    On Error Resume Next
    xTitle = ActiveDocument.BuiltInDocumentProperties("Title").Value
    xTitle = xTitle & "- " & Format((Year(Now() + 1) Mod 100), "20##") & "" & _
        Format((Month(Now() + 1) Mod 100), "0#") & "" & _
        Format((Day(Now()) Mod 100), "0#")
    Set xDlg = Dialogs(wdDialogFileSaveAs)
    xDlg.Name = xTitle
    xDlg.Show
End Sub
```

However the path is set to SaveAs at "My Document" how do i change it to be saved in the document original path , something like...

XXXX = Options.DefaultFilePath(wdStartupPath)

Comment: Try to set a path like this: `ThisDocument.Path` will return you the document's patch (the one containing the code).

Comment: could you provide more details on how exactly? appreciate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work:

```
Sub 巨集8()

Dim xDlg As Dialog
Dim xTitle As String
On Error Resume Next
xTitle = ActiveDocument.BuiltinDocumentProperties("Title").Value
xTitle = xTitle & "- " & Format((Year(Now() + 1) Mod 100), "20##") & "" & _
    Format((Month(Now() + 1) Mod 100), "0#") & "" & _
    Format((Day(Now()) Mod 100), "0#")
Set xDlg = Dialogs(wdDialogFileSaveAs)
xDlg.Name = ActiveDocument.Path & "\" & xTitle
xDlg.Show

End Sub
```

I have used Activedocument.Path property to find the current path.

Comment: it work , thank you so much. but would you mind explain the function of "\"

Comment: Yes, When we call `Activedocument.Path`, it returns the Path of Current file, i.e the folder current file is in. But to save another file in that folder we will have to put "\" & then the file name as used in referencing usual addresses. Can you also Accept this as answer :)

Comment: May i ask more about... why there are differences in Format((Month(Now() + 1) Mod 100), and Format((Day(Now()) Mod 100), "0#") , what's the meaning in "+ 1", i tried add 1 on Day then it actually adding 1 day to my current day but how come Month & Year won't share the same effect ?

Comment: I think that's because Dates are stored as numbers. So if you add 1 to that, it simply means the next day, for next month you will have to add 31 or 30 and for next year you will have to add 365.